Passing std::quoted(str) to boost::format
std::quoted is designed to work with standard IOStreams, and boost::format uses such a stream. Because boost::format is specified to work with user-defined types, the latter is not an implementation detail. So it did not surprise me that this  compiles:
boost::format("%1%") % std::quoted(std::string{"Hello, world"});

But to me, this seems on the boundary of an implementation detail. Is this supposed to work? And is this portable? std::quoted has an unspecified return type, and it's not clear that passing it via operator% would work.

std::quoted returns an object of an unspecified type and this type is extended with a friend operator<<.

To elaborate on 273K's comment - boost::format uses an internal stream to collect the formatted output.  Any user-defined type you pass to the formatter via operator% gets passed to the internal stream via operator<<.  And since std::quoted has an operator<< defined, that is why it works with boost::format.

It is supposed to work: How It Works and Rationale:

accept any types of variables, by relying on streams for the actual conversion to string. This specifically concerns user-defined types, for which the formatting options effects should be intuitively natural.

